# Elastic search and Java - Need to fetch the index and its corresponding types available for that particular index

Tags: java, elasticsearch

I am currently developing a java application which connects to elastic search using HTTP and fetch all the index and its corresponding types in a map - Key(index) and Arraylist(type). Please help

Comment: Check this
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48426474/elasticsearch-indexing-key-value-map

Answer (score 0):

One neat trick here is to use a terms aggregation on the _index and _type fields:

`GET _search
{
  "size": 0,
  "aggs": {
    "byindex": {
      "terms": {
        "field": "_index",
        "size": 10000
      },
      "aggs": {
        "by_type": {
          "terms": {
            "field": "_type",
            "size": 10
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}`

Alternatively you can use the aliases api, which returns all aliases and the indices they point to. In the case of indices without an alias, the alias is simply the index name.

Also note that as of v6 having more than one type per index is no longer allowed. Types will be removed entirely in a future version.

You can use your favorite http library to do this in java or the official elasticsearch http client for java, or one of several alternatives.

Comment: Is there any option to fetch the timestamp(Created and last modified) along with these info? Also I need to filter out the indices name which starts with ".". Please provide suggestions.